# Front-end developer interview questions

Tags: frontend

There are a lot of good interview questions (even "puzzles") for software developers here in Stack Overflow and other places, but I was wondering if anyone had some good questions for a front-end developer position. We're looking for someone who knows HTML+CSS+JS.

Some of the obvious questions:

- Have you worked with Javascript libraries? - follow-up: which, and why that one over others?
- Are you following the development of HTML5 and CSS3? - follow-up: Which features are you looking forward to the most, and why?

Do you know any good "puzzles" for a front-end developer? Maybe a JS fizz-buzz?

**edit**: changed the two questions to be a bit more open.

Comment: casperOne, this is a well written, well liked, and well answered question. You should not be closing a question like this, its kind of a dick move. Stack Overflow is not a simple Q&A format - the upvoting of answers means that even if there isn't a specific answer, usually the best of the bunch rise to the top. You should reopen this question

Comment: I agree with @BT - I'm catching up on some of the old stack overflow podcasts and Joel and Jeff both say that they want the site to become a record of knowledge. The answers below are not being debated - instead there are lots of different ways developers can be tested. The more answers the better. I arrived here because I'm interviewing front-end developers and I want a couple of questions that are good screeners for their skills - so I'm getting a legitimate use from the answers on the page.

Comment: see https://github.com/darcyclarke/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions

Comment: I have compiled a few for beginners level front end developers here http://aamirshahzad.net/interview-questions-for-front-end-developers-and-web-designers/

Comment: Lots of good stuff here already. I am surprised no one mentioned this one:  https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions

Comment: Check out this test https://tests4geeks.com/html-css-javascript-online-test

Comment: Check out the answers to the famous questions: https://github.com/yangshun/front-end-interview-handbook

Answer (score 41):

It depends on the level you are interviewing for. I recently finished up a good round of interviews for frontend positions (and found a good job! ;), here are some of the questions I was asked which I thought stood out (and were more challenging than others).

- Explain the difference between the JavaScript `call` and `apply` functions.
- Puzzle: Emulate the game "Secret Santa" where there are 3 or more participants, no participant can receive their own gift or receive more than one gift. Do this in JavaScript.
- Identify two ways in which you can clear a floated element with HTML/CSS.
- What is the difference between event bubbling and event capture?
- Describe a rendering problem you had in IE6 or IE7, and how you overcame it.
- Define the term 'closure' and give an example of it in JavaScript.
- Explain the differences between the IE and DOM standard event model.
- What is the proper way to evaluate JSON from the server, and why is this the proper way?

Answer (score 15):

The questions you propose are too easy to bluff on.  "Have you worked with javascript libraries?  Yes.  JQuery."  That doesn't tell you much.  I suggest turning the questions a little more like this:

- Describe for me how to write an extension for JQuery.
- Describe the architecture of JQuery and compare it to YUI
- What would you change about HTML5/CSS3 if you could?
- What is your favorite feature in HTML5 and how would you use it?

These get to more of a sense of understanding than mere acknowledgement of facts.

You could simply ask fizz-buzz in Javascript.  It couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 8):

I like to ask to "convert" to html a classic paper (ie, journal, magazine, etc.) to a semantically correct markup.

It helps to know if the developer knows about semantics, seo, etc.

Some other questions I like to ask:

- How to explain DOM.
- Why and when should you use div ? (ie, not every time, only when insufficient markup or need to wrap several elements)
- When using IDs, when using classes ?
- Do you use some naming convention for your ids and classes.

Therefor, I like to ask question that helps to find logical persons, not the one who knows about all functions but have a good analysis.
I think you must make a difference between skills and experiences.

and most of the question already listed by other people.

Comment: Convert to HTML a  classic paper - Brilliant. In 2015 this could be spiced up by:
* Turn a classic paper into a fully responsive website
* If this is to become a single page web app, how would you approach the content architecture
* Bonus - could you build a basic API to feed data to the API (for full stack candidates)

Answer (score 4):

- What inspires you to create good
  looking and functional websites?
- What do you think are the strengths
  of digital marketing via web and
  social media?
- Which areas of web development are you
  interested in? please range from
  most interested to least interested.
  (design, code (HTML, CSS),
  interactivity (Flash, silverlight,
  jQuery), usability, SEO etc).
- Why is it important to write good semantic code, and separate information(HTML) from layout(CSS) and behaviour (javascript)
- What is a good website for you? feel free to show examples

Answer (score -1):

What is the best user experience idea you coined and implemented in your past projects ?